# Алгоритм поиска в массиве двух максимальных значений

Tags: алгоритм, массивы, любой-язык

В результате нужно получить индексы ячеек массива с максимальными значениями.

Например, для массива `arr[4, 50, 11, 20]` это будут `1` и `3` (`arr[1]`, `arr[3]`) - индексы максимальных значений.

Comment: Можно отсортировать копию массива с сохранением начальных индексов при перестановках и в конце взять первые 2 элемента. Правда тогда потребуется массив структур и дополнительная память. Зато все просто.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, почему бы не пробежаться по массиву и держать текущие `k` наибольших значений?

Вот вам псевдокод:

```
list maximalK = empty
// инвариант: maximalK содержит отсортированный список наибольших
// k из всех просмотренных элементов
foreach e in sourceList
    p = position of e in maximalK // (binary search)
    if (p >= k)
        continue
    insert e into maximalK at position p
    if maximalK.size > k
        remove last from maximalK
```

Заметьте, что при `k == sourceList.size` вы получаете просто алгоритм сортировки (бинарными) вставками.

Временная сложность: `O(n * k)` (`n` — размер списка), за счёт сдвига при вставке. (Используя sorted map для `maximalK`, можно уменьшить до `O(n * log k)`.)